# Handling duplicate primary keys when appending

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, database-design, primary-key

On a weekly basis I would like to export from a test database into a production database once the data has been reviewed.

I've been using the following action queury:

```
Sub testCopyFromTestDB()

Dim digitalDisplaySQL As String
Dim SEMSQL As String

SEMSQL = "INSERT INTO [tblSEMMetricsAdGroups] IN 'C:\DestinationDatabase.accdb'" & _
"SELECT [TESTtblSEMMetricsAdGroups].*" & _
"FROM [TESTtblSEMMetricsAdGroups]" & _
"WHERE [TESTtblSEMMetricsAdGroups].[startDate]=#08/19/2014#;"

DoCmd.RunSQL SEMSQL   


End Sub
```

However, recently all of my records do not append due to duplicate primary keys. The primary keys for both fields are AutoNumbered. I understand the issue is the duplicate keys what I'm struggling with is sensible solution to resolve this error going forward.

It should be noted that these records do not have another field that can serve as a primary key.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: List the columns out explicitly and leave out the primary key.

Comment: What do you want to **do** when the PKs match? Do you want to leave the existing row as-is (and if yes, do you want to insert _another_ row), or update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole concept of a Primary Key is to give your record a field that makes that record absolutely, positively unique.  If an AutoNumber field can not do that, then an AutoNumber field is not the proper Primary Key.  This is cut and dry, and indisputable.

You are going to need to change your Primary Key to something that is unique and not duplicable.  Going forward, you should make your Primary Key a combination of your AutoNumber field, concatenated with the numeric value of your Date Entered field (assuming you have one, or something similar).

Alternatively, you can just import everything **but** the primary Key, unless you've got other tables that are related in some way and need the key to link them together.

Comment: This is the solution I implemented. I created a composite key in both tables that consisted of the autonumber field, the date field, and an additional integer field in the table. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have autonumbered primary keys, you should not normally be supplying a value. That's the whole point of autonumbering. If the value of the primary key has independent meaning, like the value of the primary key on table A is supposed to be the same as the value of the primary key on table B, than don't use autonumbering, because it won't work. Don't try to use a hammer to put in screws and don't try to use a screwdriver to put in nails. :-)